# how do I get that entire object instead of the foreign key. please see below code and output so you can understand

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

my question is how do I get that entire object instead of the foreign key.
please see below code and output so you can understand my question

These are my models.py

class Professor(models.Model):

```
professor_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
email = models.CharField(max_length=256)
mobile = models.CharField(max_length=256)
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

class Preference(models.Model):

```
preference_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, auto_created=True)
professor = models.ForeignKey('Professor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
rank = models.IntegerField()
created_at = models.DateTimeField()
updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
```

These are my views.py

class CreateListMixin:

```
def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(kwargs.get('data', {}), list):
        kwargs['many'] = True

    return super().get_serializer(*args, **kwargs)
```

class PreferenceViewSet(CreateListMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):

```
queryset = Preference.objects.all()
serializer_class = PreferenceSerializer
```

This is my serializers.py

class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

```
 class Meta:

    model = Preference
```

I'm getting the output as

[

{

```
    "preference_id": 1,
    "rank": 1,
    "professor": Eshwar
    "created_at": "2018-01-13T00:00:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-13T00:00:00Z"
}
```

]

what to do if I have to get professor details as object:

[

{

```
    "preference_id": 1,
    "rank": 1,
    "professor": {
                   professor_id = 1
                   name = Eshwar
                   email = ....
                   mobile = ....
                   created_at = ...
                   updated_at = ....

                 }
    "created_at": "2018-01-13T00:00:00Z",
    "updated_at": "2018-01-13T00:00:00Z"
}
```

]

my question is how do I get that entire object instead of foreign key

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a `serializer` with all the fields in the `Professor` model

```
class PreferenceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    professor = ProfessorSerializer()
    class Meta:

        model = Preference
        fields = ['other_fields','professor']
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,  it helped me, but there is a problem with other_fields

Comment: can you explain it? what problem you are facing?

Comment: Field name `other_fields` is not valid for model 'Preference'

Comment: bro other_fields are the fields you have in that model, separated like 'name','address' like that,

Comment: how I can decrease the number of calls to my database when serializing.Now, if I had 100 Preferences, to serialize everything, I would need to make 100 Database hits.